# wysiwyg editor upload image

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg

**Link git:** https://github.com/wysiwygjs/wysiwyg.js

Hey,

when using this jquery editor im trying to upload an image with the drag and drop function (or click), all that i get later when i write this out it a long data: code and it can't find any image.

How do i go about it and mabye change the code to make it work ?

**Data example:**

```
"data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQEAYABgAAD/2wBD......"
```

Comment: FYI that `data:` string is a base64 encoded version of your image. It encodes binary data into an ASCII-readable string.

Comment: Here is an exemple of converting an image to base 64 and draw it, http://jsfiddle.net/handtrix/YvQ5y/ here is the stack post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150289/how-to-convert-image-into-base64-string-using-javascript